# OutputLink not working in Flow Scope

Tags: jsf

[image]

**Confirmation.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

            <h:form>
                 <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="rightalign,leftalign">
            <h:outputText value="Salutation: "></h:outputText>
            #{registrationBean.salutation}
            <h:outputText value="First Name: "></h:outputText>
            #{registrationBean.firstname}
            <h:outputText value="Age: "></h:outputText>
            #{registrationBean.age}

             <h:outputText value="Email: "></h:outputText>
            #{registrationBean.email}
             <!--
             <h:panelGroup/>
              <h:commandButton value="continue" action="register-return"></h:commandButton>
             <h:commandButton value="back" action="register"></h:commandButton>-->
             <h:outputLink value="register.xhtml">
                 <h:outputText value="back"></h:outputText>
             </h:outputLink>
              </h:panelGrid>
             </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

**RegistrationBean.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author rshingha
 */
@Named
@FlowScoped("register")
public class RegistrationBean implements Serializable {

    private int age;
    private String firstname;
    private String salutation;
    private String email;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getSalutation() {
        return salutation;
    }

    public void setSalutation(String salutation) {
        this.salutation = salutation;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

**Index.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
        <h:commandLink action="register">
            <h:outputText value="Click here to register"></h:outputText>
        </h:commandLink>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Functionality:

Here we are navigating from index.xhtml to "register" flow scope, containing register.xhtml, register-flow.xml, confirmation.xhtml

From register.xhtml we navigate to confirmation.xhtml.

Issues:

1) I want to make a "back" output link in confirmation.xhtml to navigate back to register.xhtml

```
<h:outputLink value="register.xhtml">
                 <h:outputText value="back"></h:outputText>
             </h:outputLink>
```

But this is not working, its giving following error when I click on "back" on UI

"WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped"

Interesting thing is `<h:commandButton>` is working instead.

2) Why can't we directly run a file in directory ("register").
   Its giving following error:
   WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped

I am confused. Please help me?